# The Wasserstein Metric. Computational Optimal Transport. Weights.

Tags: algorithms, convex-optimization, entropy, regularization, optimal-transport

Let $\mu,\nu$ be two probability measures on the space $\mathbb{R}^n$, and let $\Pi(\mu,\nu)$ be the space of joint probability measures with marginals $\mu$ and $\nu$. After a discretisation of space (and entropic regularisation), one is able to compute the standard 2-Wasserstein distance

$$ W_2(\mu,\nu):= \inf_{\pi\in \Pi(\mu,\nu)} \Big( \int \|x-y\|^2 \pi(dxdy)\Big)^{1/2}, $$

using Sinkhorn algorithm (see https://arxiv.org/abs/1306.0895 ). Can anyone explain or point me to a reference for an algorithm for numerically computing the weighted Wasserstein :

$$  W_{A}(\mu,\nu):= \inf_{\pi\in \Pi(\mu,\nu)} \Big( \int \langle A(x-y) , x-y \rangle \pi(dx,dy) \Big)^{1/2}  $$

Here $A\in \mathbb{R}^{n\times n} $ is positive definite (symmetric invertible).  Or better of the entropy regularised version :

$$  W_{A,\epsilon}(\mu,\nu):= \inf_{\pi\in \Pi(\mu,\nu)} \Big( \int \langle A(x-y) , x-y \rangle \pi(dx,dy) \Big)^{1/2}+ \epsilon \int \pi(x,y) \log \pi(x,y) dxdy  $$

Comment: I don't do optimization anymore, so I might be wrong, but I think that you can find a nice description of the dual problem, and then apply an alternating minimization algorithm (which is actually exactly what Sinkhorn does). This is my own paper, so I am obviously biased, but it might help: https://arxiv.org/pdf/1906.03622.pdf

Comment: I would expect $W_{A}(\mu,\nu)=W\left({A^{-\frac{1}{2}}}_{\#}\mu, {A^{-\frac{1}{2}}}_{\#}\nu\right)$.

Comment: @Tobsn could I ask you a quick question related to these Wasserstein distances and gradient flows? Basically has anyone fixed the time step of the discrete JKO scheme and iterated the scheme to infinity to see if it converges ?  ( I know this isnt the place for it but maybe in a chatroom)

Comment: not sure if I get the question.

Comment: @Tobsn I mean this https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4204087/the-stability-of-a-gradient-flow-discrete-scheme-jko-proximal-point-referen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to support the response of Giacomo, you can use a generic Optimal Transport solver for the cost $c(x, y) = \langle A(x-y), x-y \rangle$. For instance, supposing empirical measures $\hat{\mu}$ and $\hat{\nu}$, with support $X = [x_{1}, x_{2}, \cdots, x_{n}]$ (resp. $Y$) and sample weights $\{a_{i}\}_{i=1}^{n}$ (resp. $\{b_{j}\}_{j=1}^{m}$), these are defined as,

$$\hat{\mu}(x) = \sum_{i=1}^{n}a_{i}\delta(x-x_{i}),$$
$$\hat{\nu}(y) = \sum_{i=1}^{m}b_{j}\delta(y-y_{j}),$$

You can check that using these definitions, the set $\Pi(\hat{\mu}, \hat{\nu})$ is finite (so we may substitute the inf by a min), and the optimization problem becomes:

$$\pi^{\star} = \underset{\pi \in \Pi(\hat{\mu}, \hat{\nu})}{\text{min}}\sum_{i=1}^{n}\sum_{j=1}^{m}C_{ij}\pi_{ij}$$

Now, as you may be aware, this is a (finite) linear program on the entries $\pi_{ij}$, for which there are known algorithms for solving it (e.g. Dantzig's algorithm). Sinkhorn's algorithm is a clever solution for approximating the solution $\pi^{\star}$. As Giacomo mentioned, "Computational Optimal Transport" presents a broad discussion on the subject.

Now, answering your question concerning the cost function, you can easily implement the cost on a programming language of your choice. All you need to note is that,

\begin{align*}
C_{ij} &= c(x_{i},y_{j})\\
       &= \biggr(A(x_{i}-y_{j})\biggr)^{T}(x_{i}-y_{j})\\
       &= (x_{i}-y_{j})^{T}A^{T}(x_{i}-y_{j})\\
       &= (x_{i}-y_{j})^{T}A(x_{i}-y_{j})
\end{align*}

Personally, I recommend using Python, as there are good toolboxes for Optimal Transport, such as [Python Optimal Transport (POT)](https://github.com/PythonOT/POT).

**Side-topic: Python implementation**

You may be wondering why I wrote $C_{ij} = (x_{i}-y_{j})^{T}A(x_{i}-y_{j})$. Well, the lib Scipy of Python has a high-performance function for computing pairwise distances, called [cdist](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.distance.cdist.html). Reading the documentation of this function, note that the expression for $C_{ij}$ looks a lot like the Mahalanobis distance. Indeed, $A$ in the latter expression is the $VI$ argument in the function. Thus, you can automatically program your cost function as,

````
from functools import partial
from scipy.spatial.pairwise import cdist

A = ... # definition of your positive-definite matrix of shape (p, p)
a = ... # Sample weights of \hat{\mu}, with shape (n,)
b = ... # Sample weights of \hat{\mu}, with shape (m,)
X = ... # Support of \hat{\mu}, with shape (n, p)
Y = ... # Support of \hat{\nu}, with shape (m, p)
C = cdist(X, Y, metric='mahalanobis', VI=A) # Cost matrix with shape (n, m)
pi = ot_solver(a, b, C) # optimal transport plan with shape (n, m)
```
````

Answer (score 0):

To compute the weighted Wasserstein distance you described it is sufficient to solve an optimal transport problem with respect to the cost $c(x, y) =  \langle A (x-y), x-y \rangle$. This can be done *directly* by using any algorithm that solves or approximates the optimal transport problem (for example by the entropy regularized optimal transport). I guess you could use the quite famous book "Computational Optimal Transport", which can be found at https://arxiv.org/pdf/1803.00567.pdf, as a reference. In chapter 3 they discuss entropy regularization in detail.

Ps. I would have written this in a comment but I cannot do that yet.

Comment: Yeah the question was where can one find "that algorithm" i.e can you just adapt the one for the classical $W_2$?

Comment: There are dozen of ways of computing the Wasserstein distance. Many of those are actually algorithms designed to solve the more general optimal transport problem. Arguably the most common ones are the network simplex algorithm (exact) or the Sinkhorn algorithm (approximate). Both could be used to solve the problem you give without the need for any adaptation.